# How to enable root on my Device without using a computer

Tags: root-access, nook-hd

I've been try my hardest these past couple months to figure out a way to root my Device without a computer(Got wet in April) and no success. The problem is , my Device is a BN Nook HD and Unknown Sources is blocked since software version 1.4.1 . So I can't use Kingroot etc. and It appears I can't do anything without a computer.

Any Help or Advice would be largely appreciated.

Comment: Don't you have a friend with a laptop? Ask a friend to borrow you his laptop or just call him over for a couple of hours until you root it. It's hard to imagine not being able to get across a PC today and with a PC you get plenty ways to root it...

Answer (score -1):

Actually You don't need the Computer to Root using kingRoot just download KingRoot Apk from [Open link to Download](http://kingrootapk.com/kingroot/) and Just network connection is enough to root the Device It's easy one click root and it works ;)

Comment: OP wrote: "*Unknown Sources is blocked since software version 1.4.1 . So I can't use Kingroot etc.*"